# Catching out-of-scope errors with Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am modifying a node.js library to support true asynchronous operations.

I am having troubles with Mocha and Chai to make this (a similar) test pass.

```
it('should throw an error', function() {
    expect(function() {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            throw new Error('This is my error');
        });
    }).to.throw(Error);
});
```

The problem is - because of the nextTick - that the Error is thrown out of scope of `it` and besides the test failing, Mocha also outputs the below.

```
Uncaught Error: This is my error
```

What is the proper way to structure this test in order to make it succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... in a full-fledged application what I'd do is probably use something like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to check that the method that should throw an error has been called and is throwing.

In code where you cannot do this, then the following method would trap the exception:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var domain = require("domain");

it('should throw an error', function(done) {
    var d = domain.create();
    d.on('error', function (err) {
        // Exit the current domain.
        d.exit();
        // We must execute this code at the next tick.
        process.nextTick(function () {
            console.log(err); // Just to show something on the console.
            expect(err instanceof Error).to.be.true;
            done();
        });
    });


    d.run(function () {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            throw new Error('This is my error');
        });
    });
});
```

This code creates a ["domain"](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) stored in `d`. A domain will emit `error` events on uncaught exceptions that happen in it so we run the test inside the domain (`d.run(...)`)  we've created and wait for an exception to happen (`d.on('error', ...`). We check that it is an `Error` object. (In a real test, I'd also check the error message.) When we are finished we call `done()` to tell Mocha that the asynchronous test is over.

The handler for `error` events calls `d.exit()`. This is to make it so that Mocha can catch the error normally if the assertion (`expect(err instanceof Error)`...) turns out to fail. If we do not exit the domain, then the domain will trap the error. Also, the check itself must be performed on the next tick to be outside the `d` domain.

#### Is Using `domain` A Problem?

**NO!**

The documentation for `domain` comes with some warnings about shutting down operations once an uncaught exception is caught **when running an ongoing process, like a server**. Then the thing to do is to clean what can be cleaned and exit as soon as possible. **However, using `domain` in a test does not differ from what Mocha is already doing.** The way Mocha catches unhandled exceptions in asynchronous code is by using [`process.on('uncaughtException'`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/23eb715b8530f1b578cc50de4778b45335296743/lib/runner.js#L600). Upon catching an unhandled exception Mocha [marks](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/23eb715b8530f1b578cc50de4778b45335296743/lib/runner.js#L600) the current test as failed *and continues*. Yet the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) regarding `uncaughtException` says "Don't use it, **use `domains` instead**. If you do use it, restart your application after every unhandled exception!"

Ergo, **anyone who has a problem with using `domain` should not be using Mocha in the first place**.

Comment: You should check out this: http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors See this quote "Domains and the process-wide 'uncaughtException' event are primarily useful to attempt to handle or recover from unanticipated programmer errors. For all the reasons described above, this is strongly discouraged."

Comment: @eshortie You'll have to be more specific about the problem that using domains may cause. As I said in my answer, I've used domains for script-type code without any ill-effects. If this were meant to be used in a process that has to continue running indefinitely, that would be a different matter.

Comment: Domains are deprecated, and should be avoided. https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_domain

Comment: @Esteban The documentation you linked to explicitly state "This module is **pending** deprecation. Once a replacement API has been finalized, this module will be fully deprecated." It is on its way to being deprecated but is not yet. As we speak, there's no alternative to using domains to do what the OP wants to do. I'd reserve the downvotes until they've produced the alternate API.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'll keep the downvote. I've had trouble with domains not catching some exceptions (I wish I'd remember the error type, will try to find it again).

Comment: Ok, so I took the code in my answer and just ran it with Node v4.1.0 and it worked perfectly. The problem you've encountered is elsewhere than in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to catch an exception on the incorrect function, the container for the function that throws. Also, because the function is wrapped in nextTick it is executed in a different stack and therefore the exception cannot be captured (this is simply a JS thing unfortunately).

Try this instead:

```
it ('should throw an error', function (done) {

  process.nextTick(function () {
    var myFn = function () { throw new Error() };

    expect(myFn).to.throw(Error);

    // Tell mocha the test is complete 
    done();
  });
});
```

Update: There is no proper way to structure this test to make it pass as you cannot catch the exception in this scenario. Perhaps update your code to use callbacks to handle errors:

```
function doSomethingUnsafe() {

  try {
    // Run code here that may cause exceptions...
    callback(null, 'Woohoo! No errors!');
  } catch (e) {
    callback (e, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't obvious from the question, but it's a bit more complicated that that. The nextTick is done within a function I am testing, so I'm not able to switch things around like that...

Comment: Can you not use a callback to handle the error via try/catch as per the usual Node.js convention? Or domains as Louis has explained?